# Question about Django rest framework Serializers and Views working principles

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to build REST api with Django Rest Framework and kind a having diffuculty to understand how things connected each other in terms of when we need to use the custom functions.

I have `views.py` like this

```
class myAPIView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = myTable.objects.all()
    serializer_class = mySerializer
```

this is my `serializer.py`

```
class myserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = myTable
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        #doing some operation here and save validated data

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):    
        #doing some operation here and save validated data
```

I want to add some custom function to do let's say sending emails with processed data.
so when I add `my_email_sender` function to nothing happens (nothing prints to terminal).

```
class myAPIView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = myTable.objects.all()
        serializer_class = mySerializer
    
    def my_email_func():
       print("Hey I'm email function")
       my_email_sender()
```

OTH, when do do this inside of the `serializer` its printing to the screen.

I actually really don't know this `my_email_func` should be inside of `views.py` some sort of `CRUD` operation function like `def create(), def update() etc..`
I also don't know why we cannot call it from views.py ?
Thank for your answer in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to create a `get` function, and call your function inside of it

it should be something like this:

```
class myAPIView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = myTable.objects.all()
        serializer_class = mySerializer
    
    def my_email_func():
       print("Hey I'm email function")
       my_email_sender()
  
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       my_email_func()
       return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

and then create a URL in the `urls.py` that references this view and call the endpoint with get method form postman or the browser.

Comment: I just realized the url end point to this `myAPIView` is a `POST` request so `get` method is not working in that case.

Comment: You can add any HTTP method inside your view as a function taking the same parameters